# How can I log the SQL table valued parameter value in c# code?

Tags: c#, sql-server, table-valued-parameters

I'm using TVP for one of my SQL stored procedures. I'm also logging the SQL parameters and the SP names for audit purposes. This is where I'm stuck, while trying to retrieve the TVP to log it in my log file.

This is my code:

```
private void LogStoredProc(string procName, SqlParameterCollection sqlparams)
        {
            string logMessage = str`enter code here`ing.Format("Invoking stored procedure {0} by {1} and its parameters: /n", procName, Convert.ToString(Session["User"]));
            foreach (SqlParameter param in sqlparams)
            {
                if (param.SqlDbType == SqlDbType.Structured)
                {
                    logMessage += param.Value.AsEnumerable()
                     .Select(row => row["ID"].ToString())
                     .Aggregate((s1, s2) => String.Concat(s1, "," + s2));

                }
                else
                {
                    logMessage += string.Format("{0} : {1} \n", param.ParameterName, param.Value);
                }
            }

            Log.Info(logMessage);
        }
```

The "param.Value.AsEnumerable" is throwing error. It is allowing me to convert the param.value to only 'string'.

Kindly help.

Comment: Are you always using the same source? E.g. always a datatable or always a datareader or does this need to work for anything that can be SqlDbType.Structured?

Comment: Try to first cast it to the correct type ((MyTableType) param.Value).AsEnumerable. That's assuming you have put something in there that can be converted to an Enumerable